# Easily clean-up HAML spacing in TextMate

Tags: html, textmate, haml

I'm liking HAML but running into annoyances with **tabs** vs **spaces**. Is there an easy way to convert a file from one to the other in TextMate?

I prefer tabs but I'm seeing spaces used alot...wondering if that's preferred or if that's an artifact of code I've seen posted to the web?!? I don't really care though it would seem, to me, that tabs would be simpler to work with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a macro that I wrote to convert tabs in spaces, and another one for spaces to tabs:

Just start a macro recording, do a Find and Replace (with Replace all) finding (tabs or spaces) and replacing with (the other one).

Comment: A macro is overkill in this case and likely to cause errors due to complication.  See Mirko's answer for a better, smarter solution.

Answer (score 10):

It's as simple as this: `Text > Convert > Spaces to Tabs`
I prefer tabs over spaces too (as long as they are size of 2 spaces).

**Edit:**
Textmate 2: 'Bundles > Source > Convert Tabs to Spaces'
Shortcut: ⌃⇧⌘T (ctrl + shift + cmd + t)

Now I'm all in for spaces with soft tabs always on ;)

Comment: your answer should be selected

Comment: I agree.. a macro is absolutely overkill in this case.